# Line breaks in directory using knitr/R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm currently working with R Markdown and trying to get the code, results and documentation to one pdf-file with the knit function in the end.

Within in the document, I want to set my directory with the setwd command.

```
setwd("C:/Users/Testuser/Documents/Testfolder/Testsubfolder/Testsubfolder2/Testsubfolder3/Testsubfolder4/Testsubfolder5")
```

However, the file path exceeds the width of the pdf and there is no line break so part of it is cut off at the right side. When I try to insert a page break manually, for example by pressing Enter after "Testdubfolder2", I get the following Error message:

> "Fehler in setwd("C:/Users/Testuser/Documents/Testfolder/Testsubfolder/Testsubfolder2/\n
>   Testsubfolder3/Testsubfolder4/Testsubfolder5") : kann Arbeitsverzeichnis nicht wechseln."

, which in English simply means, that the directory can't be changed. Is there any way to display the file path over two lines using the knit function? I'd be grateful for any solution or hint.

Comment: See this from the knitr examples: https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/077-wrap-output.Rmd

Comment: Your problem: German words are too long!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `file.path` to construct paths from multiple subpaths, for example:

```
setwd(file.path(
  "C:/Users/Testuser/Documents",
  "Testfolder/Testsubfolder/Testsubfolder2",
  "Testsubfolder3/Testsubfolder4/Testsubfolder5"
))
```